# Cannot find local image using React-webpack-redux-xampp

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**Dev server**

In my HeaderComponent (located in `src/components/navigation/`) this is what it looks like when i include an image from images folder:

```
let yeomanImage = require('../../images/logo.png');
```

then use it

```
<img className='img-header' src={yeomanImage}/>
```

It runs fine in dev server.

**Production**

Now when I compiled my project to production which by the way my project is subfoldered (ex. `project/projectname/myproject`). 
So I changed my **index.html** in **/dist** folder from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/app.js"></script>
```

When I run the compiled project it runs smoothly, however it can't find the image.

Comment: Can you post your webpack config file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've manage to solve the problem by changing webpack config in yeoman from

cfg/defaults.js

`publicPath: '/assets/',`

to

`publicPath: './assets/',`

and it worked!

So i guess this is what you should do for sub folder projects